# My meta box don't want to save value

Tags: metabox, post-meta

I've been fighting with that for three days and I can't figure out, why my code doesn't work?

```
<?php
    function my_custom_post_product() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Produkty', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Produkt', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Product' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Product' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Product' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Products' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Product' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Products' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No products found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No products found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Products'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our products and product specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'product', $args ); 
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_product' );
function my_taxonomies_product() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Product Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Product Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Product Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Product Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Product Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Product Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Product Category' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Product Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Product Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Product Category' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Product Categories' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'product_category', 'product', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_product', 0 );
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'product_price_box' );
function product_price_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'product_price_box',
        __( 'Product Price'),
        'product_price_box_content_callback',
        'product',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}

function product_price_box_content_callback( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'product_price_box_save' , 'product_price_box_content_nonce' );
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID,  _product_price_value_key, true);
    echo '<label for="product_price_field"></label>';
    echo '<input type="text" id="product_price_field" name="product_price_field" 
    placeholder="enter a price" value="'. esc_attr( $value ) .'" />';
}

function product_price_box_save ( $post_id ) {
    if ( !isset( $_POST['product_price_box_content_nonce'])) {
        return;
    }
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['product_price_box_content_nonce'], 'product_price_box_save')) {
        return;
    }
    if( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){
        return;
    }
    if ( !current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( !isset($_POST['product_price_field']) ) {
        return;
    }
    $save_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['product_price_field'] );
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_price_value_key', $save_data);
}
add_action('save_post', 'product_price_box_save');
```

Answer (score 0):

My code works perfectly. The  second parameter of the value is a string
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID,  '_product_price_value_key', true);